How can I send messages periodically in Android Dose mode?
Every 60 seconds in the Android app
A message must be sent to the middleware server.
There is no problem when the screen is on, but when it is turned off
The network connection seems to be lost due to doze mode.
How can I send messages periodically even when the screen is off?
I tried registering the service as foreground and using it, but
I confirmed that it did not work after a certain period of time.
Please ask for help
service as foreground is not working.

If you resolved your problem, then post an answer. Don't answer your question in the question itself.

Your approach will not work reliably on many devices due to manufacturer modifications to Android.
